# Unity 3D - Hide vertices inside chunks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertices, chunks, voxel

I am making a Minecraft-like terrain, therefor I need to combine thousands of blocks into chunks. The chunks I generate look like this:
[image]

This all looks fine. Except for the fact it still has the vertices in the middle of the chunk, like this:
[image]

I once saw a Youtube video with explanation on how to hide these vertices, since you can't actually see them while playing the game and they will take up a lot of memory when playing the game. Plus, I want to make the chunks bigger, prefered 16*16*64. If I do that right now, I will get an error:

`count <= std::numeric_limits<UInt16>::max()
UnityEngine.Mesh:CombineMeshes(CombineInstance[])`

However, I can't seem to find the video I talked about anymore, which is why I am here.

How can I update the chunk so it only shows the vertices which are actually visible?

Comment: Read this instead: http://www.sea-of-memes.com/LetsCode1/LetsCode1.html  The whole thing.

Comment: That is one way of doing it. However, it will still cause huge lag because you could still look at thousands of blocks, which will all need to be rendered. He renders the world in seperate blocks, where I generate the world in chunks. He just hides the objects which aren't visible, where I combine the objects and try to hide the sides of the blocks which aren't visible.

Comment: He works with chunks too, but as you wish, don't read it :)

Comment: I have just scanned it a little, I don't have the time to read it at the moment.